# ¿Cómo evitar que un EditText de Android muestre el teclado cuando recibe el foco (sin deshabilitar el control)?

Tags: java, android, xml, datepicker

Sucede que tengo un Edit Text de tipo textPersonName y cuando le paso el foco a otro Edit Text de tipo date me muestra el teclado virtual pero yo quiero que no me lo muestre, ya que en su lugar quiero que se muestre un dialogo que contenga un DatePicker (el cual ya lo tengo)

Esta pregunta ya la hicieron y la solucion que lei es:

```
TuEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

y en el xml:

```
android:inputType="none"
```

pero esto solo quita el foco y debo dar clic en el EditText para mostrar el dialogo del DatePicker y yo pretendo que conserve el foco pero que no muestre el teclado virtual y muestre mi dialogo de DatePicker

otra solucion que vi es quitar el foco del EditText date con el siguiente codigo:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

pero esto no es lo que pretendo realizar ya que al quitar el foco debo dar clic en el EditText para mostrar el dialogo del DatePicker repito pretendo que conserve el foco pero que no muestre el teclado virtual y muestre mi dialogo de DatePicker

A continuacion les dejo el codigo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txt_practica"
        android:hint="Practica"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Fecha de uso"
        android:id="@+id/txt_fechadeuso"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_practica"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="mostrarCalendario" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Guillermo voy a agregar una respuesta pero mi pregunta es: resumiendo,  al dar click a un EditText quieres abra un dialogo verdad?

Comment: Elenasys gracias por resp, eso que planteas ya lo hace, el detalle esta en que 1ro tengo un EditText PersonName cuando termino de escribir en el teclado virtual me da la opcion de confirmar, al dar clic a esa opcion(en mi caso es una palomita) pasa el foco al sig EditText el cual es date y automaticamente me muestra el teclado virtual pero no me muestra el dialogo, entonces si quiero ver el dialogo que tengo debo regresar atras para cerrar el teclado virtual o dar clic en el EditText, por eso quiero que cuando pase el foco del 1er EditText al 2do no me muestre el teclado solo el dialogo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes probar esto:

```
if(tuEdtittext.requestFocus()) {
esconderTecladoyAbrirElDatePicker();
}
```

También intenta haciendo uso de **[OnFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html)** :

```
 tuEdittext .setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        //Escondes el teclado y muestras el datePicker
    }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que necesitaba, me funciono con el `OnFocusChangeListener`

Answer (score 1):

Buenos días, al hacer `focusable=false` tienes el onTouchListener para abrir el DatePicker, si de todas formas necesitas hacer un click puedes hacer esto:

```
 yourEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                 v.performClick();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Yo lo que suelo hacer en estos casos es hacer un editText falso, básicamente es un textView con un linearLayout customizado de fondo para que parezca un editText, ya que customizar un TextView pre-lollipop puede dar problemas.

Por último te dejo una forma sencilla de esconder el teclado:

```
public void closeSoftKeyBoard() {
   InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
                    (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Un saludo

Comment: Comprendo, de hecho al hacer clic en el EditText puedo abrir el DatePicker lo que pretendo es que al confirmar el texto en el 1er EditText y pase el foco al 2do EditText no me muestre el teclado, solamente el DatePicker, sobre el metodo para ocultar el teclado existe alguna forma de como utilizarlo para cuando el foco cambie de un EditText al otro oculte el teclado?

Answer (score 1):

Tu lo que estas buscando es desactivar el teclado virtual de android y debemos hacer lo siguiente para eso:
1.- Debemos de ir al AndroidManifest.xml.
2.- En el debemos de agregar los siguiente:

```
<activity android:name="NombreActividad"android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
```

3.- Después de eso limpiamos la solución de android y con eso al momento en que el usuario seleccione el edittext el teclado virtual de android estara oculto.

Answer (score 0):

amigo prueba porner la siguiente atributo android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" en el manifest:

```
 <activity

        android:name=".tuactividad"
        android:label="titulo_de_tu_actividad"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

    </activity>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero no surgio ningun cambio

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes poner en los atributos(XML.) del Edittext:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="true"
```

Con el focusable en "false" se evitará que se pueda escribir en el, por lo tanto no aparecerá el teclado, y con clickable en "true"podrá ser clikeable por lo tanto aparecerá el calendario.